# Allow only one file free access but others should be password protected

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-8

I have a huge emergency here after upgrading main site to drupal 8 all my scripts in subfolders became unusable. I have following structure:

```
public_html
    --subfolder
       --subsubfolder
          .htaccess -- custom file
          certificate.php
          index.php
    .htaccess -- main Drupal8 htaccess
```

the custom file looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "SWARL Certificates generator"
AuthUserFile "/home/user/passwd"
require valid-user

<Files "^certificate\.php">
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
</Files>
```

Everything was working with drupal6 but not with drupal 8 Security is good, but how to properly setup free access to certificate.php and password protect intex.php?

Comment: tried `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteRule !certificate\.php - [F]` no help

Answer (score 0):

weird enough the following works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !certificate.php - [F]

<Files "certificate.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
</Files>

AuthType Basic
AuthName "SWARL Certificates generator"
AuthUserFile "/home/user/passwd"
require valid-user
```

I just placed both solutions simultaneously and removed slash before dot